# Trying to Make Email Field Readonly/Disabled

Tags: javascript

I have a page that I need to disable the email field on. It needs to be readonly and dimmed. I've never worked with PHP before, and I assume that's what this code is, but, I'm not sure where I would disable the email field. Here's the code I have so far:

```
/**
     * Validate our form fields
     */
    var emailField, passwordField, confirmField, formfields = FormField.GetValues(%%GLOBAL_EditAccountAccountFormFieldID%%);


    for (var i=0; i<formfields.length; i++) {
        var rtn = FormField.Validate(formfields[i].field);

        if (!rtn.status) {
            alert(rtn.msg);
            FormField.Focus(formfields[i].field);
            return false;
        }

        if (formfields[i].privateId == 'EmailAddress') {
            emailField = formfields[i];
        } else if (formfields[i].privateId == 'Password') {
            passwordField = formfields[i];
        } else if (formfields[i].privateId == 'ConfirmPassword') {
            confirmField = formfields[i];
        }
    }

    if(emailField.value.indexOf("@") == -1 || emailField.value.indexOf(".") == -1) {
        alert("%%LNG_AccountEnterValidEmail%%");
        FormField.Focus(emailField.field);
        return false;
    }

    if((passwordField.value != "" || confirmField.value != "") && (passwordField.value != confirmField.value)) {
        alert("%%LNG_AccountPasswordsDontMatch%%");
        FormField.Focus(confirmField.field);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

%%GLOBAL_FormFieldRequiredJS%%
//]]>
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't look like C# or Java or PHP, but rather JavaScript. The field can be permanently disabled in the HTML source but adding the attributes `readonly="readonly"` and `disabled="disabled"`. The JavaScript code you've posted isn't going to help you here.

Comment: The site I'm editing is a shopping cart website. The files aren't easily accessed, so while I can find the First Name, Last Name fields, I can't find the Email and Password fields because they need to be verified with the javascript. Not sure where to look.

Comment: When is this code running? Since it's validation code, it's probably running when the user submits the form. If you want to disable a field, you need to run a script when the page is loaded, it's too late when the user submits.

Comment: The page I'm editing is called "Your Account Details", so the person's info should already be in the system. What I need to do is make the email field readonly so they can't update their email after the account is created.

Answer (score 2):

To display a disabled texfield, you should output:

```
echo '<input type="email" name="name_of_field" value="email_to_display@gmail.com" disabled>';
```

Example:

[image]

See here (and have a look at the code):
[Example](https://devpgsv.com/tests/disableInput.php)

Perhaps if we had a link to the website we could have a look a it :)

Comment: Read his comment, he doesn't have access to the original PHP script that creates the page, he can only run Javascript after it's loaded.

Comment: I was answering while he wrote that XD

Comment: I just added a picture of the page above. Unfortunately, you can only see it when logged into the site, so I can't share login details.

Comment: Could you post also the link to that website? I registered but I can't find that page

Comment: www.oapfieldapparel.com

Comment: Oh... I registered in a different web ... .XDDD

Comment: Do you have access to css?